# Linq - Is operations order relevant?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, t-sql

I have some slow linq queries and need to optimize them. I have read about compiled queries and setting the merge option in NoTracking in my readonly operations.
But I think my problem is that I have too many Includes so the number of joins done in the DB is huge.

```
context.ExampleEntity
      .Include("A")
      .Include("B")
      .Include("D.E.F")
      .Include("G.H")
      .Include("I.J")
      .Include("K.M")
      .Include("K.N")
      .Include("O.P")
      .Include("Q.R")
      .Where(a => condition1 || complexCondition2)
```

My doubt is, if I put the Where before the Includes, would this filter ExampleEntity objects before making all the joins?? Im not sure about how linq queries are translated to SQL

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but an interesting approach to `Include`: [Entity Framework - compile safe Includes](http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post/Entity-Framework-compile-safe-Includes.aspx)

Comment: You can use SQL Profiler or EF Profiler (http://efprof.com/) to see what exact queries are executed against the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Yes".
Each sub-query passes it's results to the next.  Moving the `Where` first will filter, *then* perform the includes against a potentially smaller set.

Whether that makes sense in the context of your specific query is up to you to decide.